# Performance difference between various specifiers in range_declaration of range-based for loop

Tags: c++

I have seen many types of type specifiers used while declaring range for a range-based for-loop like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
 
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 
    for (const int& i : v) // access by const reference
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    for (auto i : v) // access by value, the type of i is int
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    for (auto&& i : v) // access by forwarding reference, the type of i is int&
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    const auto& cv = v;
 
    for (auto&& i : cv) // access by f-d reference, the type of i is const int&
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

// some aren't mentioned here, I just copied this snippet from cppreference
```

Which of these is expected to perform faster (after -O2 or -O3 optimisation)? Does the choice depends on the data type of vector, or on the operation(s) we're performing inside the loop.

PS: `cout` inside the loops is just for demo.

Comment: It is mostly the same as for parameter: "big" / "heavy to copy" objects by (const) reference. For "small" / "fast to copy" objects, it doesn't really matter and if it does, you have to measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of them is *expected* to perform faster or slower.  You have to measure to find out on your specific platform.  Or read the assembly code, which you may find out is identical for some or all of them (you can try here: https://godbolt.org/).

As an aside, if your loop bodies are actually writing to `cout` on every iteration, it will not matter which loop style you use, because `cout` is slow and iterating integers in a vector is fast.